# Как правильно положить jar файл в контейнер?

Tags: java, docker

В интернете куча примеров как работать с `docker` + `java`. Но все они примерно [такие](https://github.com/redhat-developer-demos/java-container/blob/master/Dockerfile.openjdk#L5).

Проблема в том, что когда я делаю `mvn clean package` мой `jar` файл содержит в имени номер версии. Неужели необходимо каждый раз прописывать в `Dockerfile` номер версии или есть какой-то способ обойти это ?

Comment: Можно попробовать указать `ADD target/*.jar /usr/src/myapp/` и потом `CMD java <MainClass>`, т.е. использовать запуск класса из `classpath`, а не через параметр `-jar`. Предварительно нужно указать `WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp` или добавить параметр `-cp /usr/src/myapp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скопировать jar-файл с указанием wildcard (*) вместо версии
Пример Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
COPY target/myapp*.jar /opt/myapp.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/myapp.jar"]
```

Копировать можно и в другую директорию